# Организация класса

Tags: java, swing

Делаю программу с использованием swing. Смысл в том, что т.к. все взаимосвязано в классе из-за ActionListener'ов, то все в одном файле. Что-то искать или менять в нем крайне неудобно. Как правильно организовать класс и вынести из него все классы-слушатели, но так, чтобы они видели все переменные моего текущего класса ?

Вы можете оценить масштаб трагедии [тут](https://github.com/Faoxis/KatinDipsach/blob/master/GUI/src/main/java/com/faoxis/gui/MainWindow.java).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы либо можете инкапсулировать слушатели в отдельные классы, а ссылки на необходимые члены класса им передать через конструктор. 
Однако я рекомендовал бы вам использовать шину событий, она позволяет сильно уменьшить связность компонентов в gui приложении. Неплохая базовая реализация EventBus есть например в [google guava](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/EventBusExplained)